# Implications of a correct proof of the Riemann hypothesis?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-hypothesis, prime-gaps

What are some major implications of a proof of the Riemann hypothesis?

Comment: "Tons" of major applications can be found at this [MO-question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17209/consequences-of-the-riemann-hypothesis).

Comment: 1st of all : the [Riemann explicit formula $\psi(x) = x - \sum_\rho \frac{x^\rho}{\rho}-\ln 2\pi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Proof_sketch) relates directly the zeros of $\zeta(s)$ to the regularity of the distribution of prime numbers.